# StdIn.Writeline Fails in ASP sending strings to PowerShell

Tags: powershell, vbscript, asp-classic

I am updating a Classic ASP webpage. It seems that if you try to use StdIn.Writeline to send command to PowerShell it fails. It behaves like the command interpreter only accepts commands as part of creating the session.

Does anyone have any working examples of passing supplemental commands to an open PowerShell execution from a Classic (Not ASP.Net) web page?

```vb
Command = "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe -NoExit -inputformat none -ExecutionPolicy bypass  -NonInteractive -noprofile -Command ""& {""$PSVersionTable.PSVersion""; ""Add-PSSnapIn VMware* -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue""; 2>&1} "

Set oExec = WshShell.Exec(Command)

If oExec.Status = 0 Then
    oExec.StdIn.Writeline("Dir 2>&1")
    oExec.StdIn.Writeline("Exit")
    oExec.StdIn.Close()
    Do While oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream <> True
        Response.Write oExec.StdOut.ReadLine
    Loop
End If
```

When I try to keep the command interpreter open and use `StdIn.Writeline` to send additional commands, including the exit command, it never closes and I have to kill the process on the IIS server.

If I remove the `-NoExit` switch, it does close after running the string passed, and obviously I can't send additional commands to run.

Any ideas on how to get PowerShell to work like `%comspec%` does?